# Why do we need @GeneratedValue?

Tags: java, jpa

Does the modern databases support auto-increment ability? 
So what is the purpose of `@Generatedvalue`? 
It seems that with this way we are replacing DB functionality.

Comment: Do all RDBMS support auto increment ? no. Do all RDBMS support the same value generation (sequence, autoincrement, etc) ? no. Do all classes need value generation ? no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark `id` as auto incrementing. And when I say "mark it" I mean: "Hey SQL! This column is auto incrementing!" Can you declare primary key column in SQL without declaring it as auto incrementing? Yes, you can of course! Therefore, if you declare your `id` column as something like:

```
@Id
long id;
```

Equivalent in MySQL will be like:

```
id bigint(20) primary key
```

If you declare it as:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
long id;
```

equivalent in MySQL will be:

```
id bigint(20) primary key auto_increment
```